# Initial delay whilst looping a function every n seconds in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to loop the function "logger" every second, ideally start and stop at certain times of the day too, however I haven't worked out the best way to do that yet. I've noticed in the log file that there's a delay between the first and second entry when printing the data. How do I solve this problem?

> [u'(LON:SXX)'] - [u'14.38'] - [u'3.88M/6.72M'] - 12:12:36
>
> [u'(LON:SXX)'] - [u'14.38'] - [u'3.88M/6.72M'] - 12:12:43
>
> [u'(LON:SXX)'] - [u'14.38'] - [u'3.88M/6.72M'] - 12:12:44
>
> [u'(LON:SXX)'] - [u'14.38'] - [u'3.88M/6.72M'] - 12:12:45

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import time

starttime=time.time()

driver = webdriver.WebDriver()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.uk/finance?q=LON:SXX') 

def logger():
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        # get the current price & time
        tme = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        current_price = [price.text for price in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="price-panel"]/div[1]/span') if price.text]
        volume = [vol.text for vol in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]') if vol.text]
        symbol = [sym.text for sym in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span') if sym.text]
        f.write ("%s - %s - %s - %s \n" % (symbol, current_price, volume, tme))
        f.close

while True:
    logger()
    time.sleep(1.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1.0))
```

Comment: Hint: check how long `driver.get` takes to complete. You do it only once and never measure that time.

Comment: I've added a `time.sleep(5)` just after `driver.get` which appears to have resolved the issue temporarily.  I'll measure the time too as you've suggested. What's the best way to start and stop the function at certain times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may choose one of this:
- use your OS crontab, 
- use python crontab module
- use a scheduler module

Please see bellow your code example modified to use the python apscheduler module:
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import time

#to install 'apscheduler' use this command 'pip install apscheduler'
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

#init the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()


starttime=time.time()

driver = webdriver.WebDriver()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.uk/finance?q=LON:SXX') 

#here we are decor the logger function 

@sched.interval_schedule(seconds=1)
def logger():
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        # get the current price & time
        tme = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        current_price = [price.text for price in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="price-panel"]/div[1]/span') if price.text]
        volume = [vol.text for vol in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]') if vol.text]
        symbol = [sym.text for sym in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span') if sym.text]
        f.write ("%s - %s - %s - %s \n" % (symbol, current_price, volume, tme))
        f.close


sched.start()
```